# How to save tkinter table as an image

Tags: python, save, tkinter, draw

I am drawing a table using tKinter. I was wondering if there was a way to export the table as an image.

```
for r in range(numberOfRows):
     for c in range(numberOfColumns):
         l = tk.Label(root, text=someText, relief="solid", height=5, width=10, bg="white")
         l.grid(row=r, column=c)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Probably not from inside Python. You might want to look for tools to automate taking a screenshot.

Comment: If the table is drawn on a canvas widget you can save it using PIL and the logic found here: http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2009-November/002114.html

Answer (score 1):

You can always go the draw-it-yourself way. There are several modules out there that allow you draw an image. Take the coordinates of your table, column width and so on and draw it into the image.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screen shot of it.

```
import PIL.ImageGrab as ImageGrab

screenshot = ImageGrab.grab().load()

rgb = screenshot[0, 0] 
print rgb
```

**rgb** would return the color value of any pixel on screen.